# Optimal basis set of Gaussian functions for describing a quantum system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, wavefunction, orbital-motion, computational-physics

Copy from here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/285044/optimal-basis-set-of-gaussian-functions-for-describing-a-quantum-system

This question arose during the discussion of the previous questions: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/284809/why-does-the-minimum-eigenvalue-change-dramatically-when-one-basis-function-is-a#284841 and https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/284910/finding-excited-states-using-the-condition-of-wave-functions-orthogonality

Brief description of the problem:

Consider the following system with the Hamiltonian: $H=-\frac{1}{2}\Delta-\frac{1}{r}+\frac{25}{8}\rho^2-5/2$, where $r=(\rho,z,\phi)$ is a coordinate in the cylindrical system. Physically, this Hamiltonian describes a hydrogen atom in a magnetic field equal to 5 (in dimensionless units).
In order to solve this problem by the matrix method, it is necessary to choose a set of basis functions. To describe ground and excited states with the z component of the angular momentum m = 0 (1s, 2s, 3d (m = 0), 3s ...), a Gaussian basis set is well suited. Such basis functions have the following form: $\psi_j=e^{-b_{j} z^2}e^{-a_{j} \rho^2}$, where $a_{j}$ and $b_{j}$ are parameters. The task is reduced to the correct finding of parameters.

The parameters describing the ground state (1s) with high accuracy were found in this work (see here https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.05553 or here https://pubs.aip.org/aip/jcp/article/147/24/244108/195534/Accurate-and-balanced-anisotropic-Gaussian-type). But the basis presented in this article does not describe excited states (2s, 3d (m = 0), 3s ...) well, since there are not enough basis functions to describe them. The basis set parameters presented in this article has a complex structure, so increasing the basis set functions in this case is a difficult task.

It seems that a more general way to find the basis set of parameters is presented in this article (see here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q74hAn0UAdNd8DtPkoCsdYPkr61-xhr2/view?usp=sharing or here https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/pssb.2220930140). The sets of parameters that the authors use are geometric progressions: 
$\alpha_j=\alpha_{j-1}(\frac{\alpha_N}{\alpha_1})^{1/(N-1)}$

$\beta_j=\alpha_{j-1}(\frac{\beta_M}{\beta_1})^{1/(M-1)}$, 
where $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_N$, $\beta_1$ and $\beta_M$ are the first and the last parameters. About finding these parameters, the authors write the following: "the parameters $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_N$, $\beta_1$ and $\beta_M$ were varied in a four dimensional optimization search which minimized the sum of the eigen-values of interest" and "We have performed the calculations presented in this paper with a basis with ten Gaussians in the $\rho$ direction and twelve Gaiissians in the z direction, for a total of 120 different basis functions.". I really don't understand what that means?

Energy values from the articles: 
ground state (1s) = - 1.3793 (exact value = -1.380398866427)
the first excited state (2s) = -0.19335 (exact value = -0.193746709717)
the second excited state (3d (m=0)) = -0.07365 
the third excited state (3s) = -0.03835

All these states should have the same structure of the basis set function ($\psi_j=e^{-b_{j} z^2}e^{-a_{j} \rho^2}$) due to the m=0 (the z component of the angular momentum).

I have a few questions: 
I really can't understand what the authors mean in varied optimization search of the parameters $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_N$, $\beta_1$ and $\beta_M$, could you please explain to me what that means?

Why do the parameters ($\alpha_1$, $\alpha_N$, $\beta_1$ and $\beta_M$) have different indexes, shouldn't their number be the same? Since they are paired in the basis function.

I would be glad to any comments on solving the problem.

I would like to draw attention to the fact that to get the energy from the Aldrich, C., & Greene, R. L article it's needed the value from the table 1 to subtract the field value and divide by 2 (this is due to the fact that the authors of this article do not take into account the spin). For example for 2s state: value from the table 1 for magnetic field = 5 is equal 4.6133 so the energy of the 2s state = (4.6133 - 5)/2 = -0,19335

Comment: "The optimal basis" to solve the problem is the actual solution of the problem. The choice of a finite number of approximating functions in this case is simply an ad-hoc procedure that doesn't actually care about a rational solution strategy to the mathematical problem. While it has a long established history in physics (and especially in chemistry where experimental accuracy limits the theory to rough estimates), it's really not what you should be learning about either the physics or the mathematics of these equations, IMHO.